# No visible @interface for 'NavigationViewController' declares the selector 'initWithRootViewController:'

Tags: ios, objective-c

My following code everything is in the `AppDelegate.m` file of my Xcode project.

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import "NavigationViewController.h"
    #import "HubViewController.h"

    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[NavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[HubViewController alloc] init]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
    }

    @end
```

I keep getting an error on the `'self.window.rootViewController' line stating 'No visible @interface for NavigationViewController' declares the selector 'initWithRootViewController:'`. It also states it as an 1ARC Issue1 in the error log. (automatic reference counting issue). Are there any known solutions to this problem that are out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're just starting out with objective-c and iOS development. You could create your own NavigationViewController class, but what you're probably intending to do is use a [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - which is a pre-canned container view controller that handles push/pop style navigation. It very often serves as the root view controller in an application.

**Background Color:**

You're navigation controller's view is going to consume the entire [***frame***](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html) of the window. So you should instead set:

```
self.window.rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

***ARC Error:***

For the ARC error you'll need to post more information.

**iTunes U:**

I recommend that you download and watch the iOS Stanford Univserity iOS Programming course from iTunes U. It's a great intro, and free.